# How to extract verb phrases today?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, textacy

For a project on NLP I need to extract verb phrases from a list of sentences. I have read some older posts from StackOverflow and watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgGHwIWu-kU). All was very helpful in understanding my problem and learning about possible patterns, but all code refers to a textacy module function:

```
textacy.extract.matches(txt, patterns=pattern)
```

I believe this code is not usable anymore, as I get the error that the module is not callable.

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have looked at SpaCy's matcher to solve my problem but I am not sure if this can be used for verb phrase extraction as well. Does anyone have an updated way of extracting verb phrases?

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and output? spaCy's matchers (maybe the DependencyMatcher in this case) should have no problem doing what you need. https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching

Answer (score 3):

Looks like current textacy docs change

textacy.extract.matches

to

textacy.extract.matches.token_matches

for your use-case.